# Replace string in template with csv data

Tags: php, string, replace

I using `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22`. I am having the following csv file that I read in:

```
Product;Category;Manufacturer;Price;hasWlan
Product 8;Category 1;Manifacturer - 9;3;f
Product 7;Category 8;Manifacturer - 1;5;t
Product 9;Category 8;Manifacturer - 1;10;t
Product 9;Category 2;Manifacturer - 7;7;f
Product 5;Category 9;Manifacturer - 2;7;t
Product 5;Category 3;Manifacturer - 7;10;t
Product 6;Category 10;Manifacturer - 4;1;t
Product 5;Category 7;Manifacturer - 2;1;t
Product 5;Category 1;Manifacturer - 6;6;t
```

I would like to replace the following template by the csv values:

**Template:**

`@attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer).`

**Wanted Result:**

```
Product 8 has the Category 1 from the Manufacturer - 9.
Product 7 has the Category 8 from the Manufacturer - 1.

etc.
```

I tried the following php script:

```
<?php
class StringTemplate
{
    public function process($text, $singleVariable, $data) {

        // 1. Replace Variables
        $pattern = '@attr(' . $singleVariable . ')'; 
        $text = str_replace($pattern, $data, $text);

        // return final result
        return $text;
    }

}

/*******************/
/***EXAMPLE USAGE***/
/*******************/

// 1. Read in csv
$csvFile = '/home/ubuntu/workspace/src/SampleText.csv';

echo "\n";
$StringTemplate = new StringTemplate();
$template = "@attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). ";

$row = 0;
$vars = array();
if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $StringTemplate->process($template, $vars, $data[$c]);
    }
    if($row == 0) {
        $vars = $data;
        echo print_r($vars) . "\n";
    }
    echo "####################### \n";
    $row++;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

However, I receive the following output currently:

```
$ php src/testFile.php 

@attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). Array
(
    [0] => Product
    [1] => Category
    [2] => Manufacturer
    [3] => Price
    [4] => hasWlan
)
1
####################### 
@attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). @attr(Product) has the @attr(Category) from the @attr(Manufacturer). ####################### 
...
```

As you can see the data does not get replaced within my script.

Any suggestions why this is the case?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `$singleVariable` is __array__.

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you for your reply! Do I need another loop to make this code work? ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `$singleVariable` **is not** single variable (rename it, don't confuse yourself and others), you should create an array of replacements from it. So, I think you should replace

```
$pattern = '@attr(' . $singleVariable . ')';
```

with:

```
$pattern = [];
foreach ($singleVariable as $variable) {
    $pattern[] = '@attr(' . $variable . ')'; 
}
```

Rest of the code of the function stays the same. As `str_replace` can work with arrays, everything should work.
Also, you should fix your `while` loop to this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    // here you get headers, there's no need to increment `$row` any more than here
    if ($row == 0) {
        $vars = $data;
        $row++;
        //echo print_r($vars) . "\n";
    }
    // here you replace - array of `$vars` to array of `$data`
    echo $StringTemplate->process($template, $vars, $data);
}
```